# Printing abstract syntax tree using ppx_deriving

Tags: ocaml, abstract-syntax-tree

Could some please tell me why this code is not compiling. I am trying to print the abstract syntax tree using ppx_deriving library.

```
type prog = command list
[@@deriving show]
and command =
   | Incv | Decv
   | Incp | Decp
   | Input  | Output
   | Loop of command list
   [@@deriving show]

let _ = Format.printf "%s" (show_prog ([Incv, Incv]))

hello:brainfuckinter mukeshtiwari$ ocamlbuild -package ppx_deriving.std  ast.byte
+ /Users/mukeshtiwari/.opam/4.02.1/bin/ocamlc.opt -c -I /Users/mukeshtiwari/.opam/4.02.1/lib/ppx_deriving -o ast.cmo ast.ml
File "ast.ml", line 10, characters 28-37:
Error: Unbound value show_prog
Command exited with code 2.
Compilation unsuccessful after building 2 targets (1 cached) in 00:00:00.
hello:brainfuckinter mukeshtiwari$ ocaml
    OCaml version 4.02.1
```

Comment: What is show_prog in your program ?

Comment: @alifirat I was suggested to use it on #ocaml channel to derive the show instance of type prog similar to https://github.com/whitequark/ppx_deriving/blob/master/src_examples/print_test.ml

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `-use-ocamlfind` as first argument of ocamlbuild. It should solve the issue.

(You also have a typo in `[Incv, Incv]`, the `,` should be a `;`.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I noticed this when compiler yelled at me.